# launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses build error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, build

I tried build unity project, but after insert Firebase and applovin SDK it always crashed

`Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Note: /someProj copy/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/IL2CPP/Gradle/unityLibrary/src/main/java/com/unity3d/player/UnityPlayerActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /someProj
copy/Library/Bee/Android/Prj/IL2CPP/Gradle/unityLibrary/src/main/java/com/unity/androidnotifications/UnityNotificationManager.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.

> 1 exception was raised by workers:
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class androidx.annotation.AnimRes found in modules annotation-1.3.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0) and jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar)
> Duplicate class androidx.annotation.AnimatorRes found in modules annotation-1.3.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0) and jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar)
> Duplicate class androidx.annotation.AnyRes found in modules annotation-1.3.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0) and jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar)
> Duplicate class androidx.annotation.AnyThread found in modules annotation-1.3.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0) and jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.0.0.jar)....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete all (AAR or JAR) files inside assets / plugin / android

Comment: u right, its works ;)